# LaTeX install path on OS X

Tags: installing, mac, paths

I run the MacTeX 2012 installer and it installed a bunch of apps and tools under `/Applications/TeX`. However, I can't find the latex executables.

There is no `/usr/texbin`, no `/usr/local/texlive`. If I try to generate a PDF in TeXShop it returns an error, because it doesn't find the executables.

Shouldn't the MacTeX installer install them too? Where are they located?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Reinstall

The MacTeX installer should have installed them in `/usr/texbin` or `/Library/TeX/texbin`. To check if the executables are installed anywhere, use the following:

```
$ which pdftex
```

It should return:

```
/usr/texbin/pdftex
```

Or, for OS X 10.11 and above:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdftex
```

If it doesn't, you'll have to re-install MacTeX.

## Redownload

It could be your package is corrupt, to check run the following from the directory in which `MacTeX.pkg` is located:

```
$ openssl md5 MacTeX.pkg
```

The resulting hash should match the md5 sum from [the download page](http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html).

If it the checksum doesn't match you should [download it](http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) again, I recommend using the [torrent](http://www.tug.org/mactex/MacTeX.pkg.torrent).

Comment: I doesn't return anything unfortunatelly. The folder `/usr/texbin` doesn't exist on my machine. I tried reinstalling MacTeX 3 times now.

Comment: @Jawap Usually `/usr/texbin` is a symbolic link. Do you have `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin`?

Comment: Hmm, reïnstalling fixed it in my case. You could try running `FixMacTeX2012.pkg` (located in `/Application/TeX`). When and how did you obtain the installer?

Comment: Well running FixMaxTeX2012.pkg added a symbolic link at `/usr/texbin` pointing to `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin`. However I have no `/Library/TeX` folder... I also don't have a `/usr/local/texlive` folder :-(

Comment: @Jawap have you verified your package using the instruction I added?

Comment: @Silex Thanks a lot. I somehow got the wrong package. I downloaded it again from the official website and it worked fine this time. I would vote up, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks Silke for the helpful answer! @ Silke, for example if I enter $ which pdftex, then the terminal returned /usr/textbin/pdftex, and I can also find things like TexShop icon in Application/Tex folder, when I'm trying to insert a picture, shall I put the pdf of the picture into the Tex folder or the use folder?

Comment: @CatherineChen: The picture that should be included in your document should be located in the working directory of your document.

Comment: `Monas-MacBook-Pro:~ mona$ which pdftex
Monas-MacBook-Pro:~ mona$` hence which pdftex returns nothing

Comment: $ openssl md5 MacTeX.pkg
MacTeX.pkg: No such file or directory

Comment: @MonaJalal The actual command is `openssl md5 [path to MacTeX.pkg]`. Either change to the directory in which `MacTeX.pkg` is located or modify the path  (eg: `openssl md5 ~/Downloads/MacTeX.pkg`).

Comment: I have also updated the instructions to refer to the correct checksum on the download page.

Comment: I found it in `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin/`. This was mentioned in `/Applications/TeX/Docs and Spell Utilities/READ ME FIRST.pdf`